# OpenGL: How to rotate a group of polygons about a common point

Tags: opengl, graphics, rotation

I have a group of polygons that I need to rotate while preserving their spatial inter-relationships.

The situation is not unlike trying to position a hat so that it stays on the head of a person, in profile, who is nodding their head up and down. As the "head" tilts forward, rotating around a point in the "neck," the "hat" needs to match the tilt but also swing around that point in the "neck" so that it stays on the "head."

Rotating the "head" is no problem. I simply translate it to the origin, perform the rotation, and then undo the translation. It's the "hats" that have me stumped. The code I have is using matrix stacks.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple, just translate so the point you are rotating around is the origin and rotate then translate back. It'll be the same matrix combination that you use for the head.

Comment: Haha. That occurred to me right after I hit post. I think just spelling out the problem made the answer clear. But many thanks for the quick reply.